# Python Script timeout error Ambari

Tags: java, python, hadoop, ambari

I'm getting some errors during **Install, Start and Test** phase, `Python script has been killed due to timeout after waiting 900 secs`

attaching the log here

```
stderr: 
Python script has been killed due to timeout after waiting 900 secs
 stdout:
2015-04-16 16:43:04,609 - Execute['mkdir -p /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/AMBARI-artifacts/;     curl -kf -x "" --retry 10     http://vagrant-centos65.vagrantup.com:8080/resources//UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK7.zip -o /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/AMBARI-artifacts//UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK7.zip'] {'environment': ..., 'not_if': 'test -e /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/AMBARI-artifacts//UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK7.zip', 'ignore_failures': True, 'path': ['/bin', '/usr/bin/']}
2015-04-16 16:43:04,683 - Group['hadoop'] {'ignore_failures': False}
2015-04-16 16:43:04,685 - Adding group Group['hadoop']
2015-04-16 16:43:04,755 - Group['nobody'] {'ignore_failures': False}
2015-04-16 16:43:04,756 - Modifying group nobody
2015-04-16 16:43:04,816 - Group['users'] {'ignore_failures': False}
2015-04-16 16:43:04,817 - Modifying group users
2015-04-16 16:43:04,853 - Group['nagios'] {'ignore_failures': False}
2015-04-16 16:43:04,854 - Adding group Group['nagios']
2015-04-16 16:43:04,896 - Group['knox'] {'ignore_failures': False}
2015-04-16 16:43:04,896 - Adding group Group['knox']
2015-04-16 16:43:04,950 - User['nobody'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'nobody']}
2015-04-16 16:43:04,951 - Modifying user nobody
2015-04-16 16:43:05,025 - User['hive'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'hadoop']}
2015-04-16 16:43:05,026 - Adding user User['hive']
2015-04-16 16:43:05,131 - User['oozie'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'users']}
2015-04-16 16:43:05,131 - Adding user User['oozie']
2015-04-16 16:43:05,199 - User['nagios'] {'gid': 'nagios', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'hadoop']}
2015-04-16 16:43:05,200 - Adding user User['nagios']
2015-04-16 16:43:05,384 - User['ambari-qa'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'users']}
2015-04-16 16:43:05,385 - Adding user User['ambari-qa']
2015-04-16 16:43:05,504 - User['flume'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'hadoop']}
2015-04-16 16:43:05,505 - Adding user User['flume']
2015-04-16 16:43:05,612 - User['hdfs'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'hadoop']}
2015-04-16 16:43:05,613 - Adding user User['hdfs']
2015-04-16 16:43:05,682 - User['knox'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'hadoop']}
2015-04-16 16:43:05,683 - Adding user User['knox']
2015-04-16 16:43:05,738 - User['storm'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'hadoop']}
2015-04-16 16:43:05,738 - Adding user User['storm']
2015-04-16 16:43:05,806 - User['mapred'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'hadoop']}
2015-04-16 16:43:05,806 - Adding user User['mapred']
2015-04-16 16:43:05,859 - User['hbase'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'hadoop']}
2015-04-16 16:43:05,860 - Adding user User['hbase']
2015-04-16 16:43:05,916 - User['tez'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'users']}
2015-04-16 16:43:05,917 - Adding user User['tez']
2015-04-16 16:43:05,972 - User['zookeeper'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'hadoop']}
2015-04-16 16:43:05,972 - Adding user User['zookeeper']
2015-04-16 16:43:06,041 - User['kafka'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'hadoop']}
2015-04-16 16:43:06,042 - Adding user User['kafka']
2015-04-16 16:43:06,097 - User['falcon'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'hadoop']}
2015-04-16 16:43:06,098 - Adding user User['falcon']
2015-04-16 16:43:06,161 - User['sqoop'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'hadoop']}
2015-04-16 16:43:06,162 - Adding user User['sqoop']
2015-04-16 16:43:06,228 - User['yarn'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'hadoop']}
2015-04-16 16:43:06,229 - Adding user User['yarn']
2015-04-16 16:43:06,287 - User['hcat'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'hadoop']}
2015-04-16 16:43:06,287 - Adding user User['hcat']
2015-04-16 16:43:06,345 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/changeUid.sh'] {'content': StaticFile('changeToSecureUid.sh'), 'mode': 0555}
2015-04-16 16:43:06,346 - Writing File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/changeUid.sh'] because it doesn't exist
2015-04-16 16:43:06,346 - Changing permission for /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/changeUid.sh from 644 to 555
2015-04-16 16:43:06,347 - Execute['/var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/changeUid.sh ambari-qa /tmp/hadoop-ambari-qa,/tmp/hsperfdata_ambari-qa,/home/ambari-qa,/tmp/ambari-qa,/tmp/sqoop-ambari-qa 2>/dev/null'] {'not_if': 'test $(id -u ambari-qa) -gt 1000'}
2015-04-16 16:43:06,469 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/changeUid.sh'] {'content': StaticFile('changeToSecureUid.sh'), 'mode': 0555}
2015-04-16 16:43:06,470 - Execute['/var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/changeUid.sh hbase /home/hbase,/tmp/hbase,/usr/bin/hbase,/var/log/hbase,/hadoop/hbase 2>/dev/null'] {'not_if': 'test $(id -u hbase) -gt 1000'}
2015-04-16 16:43:06,599 - Directory['/etc/hadoop/conf.empty'] {'owner': 'root', 'group': 'root', 'recursive': True}
2015-04-16 16:43:06,599 - Creating directory Directory['/etc/hadoop/conf.empty']
2015-04-16 16:43:06,600 - Link['/etc/hadoop/conf'] {'not_if': 'ls /etc/hadoop/conf', 'to': '/etc/hadoop/conf.empty'}
2015-04-16 16:43:06,623 - Creating symbolic Link['/etc/hadoop/conf']
2015-04-16 16:43:06,651 - File['/etc/hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh'] {'content': InlineTemplate(...), 'owner': 'hdfs'}
2015-04-16 16:43:06,651 - Writing File['/etc/hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh'] because it doesn't exist
2015-04-16 16:43:06,652 - Changing owner for /etc/hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh from 0 to hdfs
2015-04-16 16:43:06,684 - Repository['HDP-2.2'] {'base_url': 'http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/updates/2.2.4.2', 'action': ['create'], 'components': [u'HDP', 'main'], 'repo_template': 'repo_suse_rhel.j2', 'repo_file_name': 'HDP', 'mirror_list': None}
2015-04-16 16:43:06,710 - File['/etc/yum.repos.d/HDP.repo'] {'content': Template('repo_suse_rhel.j2')}
2015-04-16 16:43:06,711 - Writing File['/etc/yum.repos.d/HDP.repo'] because it doesn't exist
2015-04-16 16:43:06,711 - Repository['HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.20'] {'base_url': 'http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.20/repos/centos6', 'action': ['create'], 'components': [u'HDP-UTILS', 'main'], 'repo_template': 'repo_suse_rhel.j2', 'repo_file_name': 'HDP-UTILS', 'mirror_list': None}
2015-04-16 16:43:06,722 - File['/etc/yum.repos.d/HDP-UTILS.repo'] {'content': Template('repo_suse_rhel.j2')}
2015-04-16 16:43:06,722 - Writing File['/etc/yum.repos.d/HDP-UTILS.repo'] because it doesn't exist
2015-04-16 16:43:06,722 - Package['unzip'] {}
2015-04-16 16:43:07,144 - Skipping installing existent package unzip
2015-04-16 16:43:07,145 - Package['curl'] {}
2015-04-16 16:43:07,463 - Skipping installing existent package curl
2015-04-16 16:43:07,464 - Package['hdp-select'] {}
2015-04-16 16:43:07,724 - Installing package hdp-select ('/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install hdp-select')
2015-04-16 16:43:11,315 - Execute['mkdir -p /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/AMBARI-artifacts/ ;   curl -kf -x ""   --retry 10 http://vagrant-centos65.vagrantup.com:8080/resources//jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz -o /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/AMBARI-artifacts//jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz'] {'environment': ..., 'not_if': 'test -e /usr/jdk64/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java', 'path': ['/bin', '/usr/bin/']}
2015-04-16 16:43:11,323 - Skipping Execute['mkdir -p /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/AMBARI-artifacts/ ;   curl -kf -x ""   --retry 10 http://vagrant-centos65.vagrantup.com:8080/resources//jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz -o /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/AMBARI-artifacts//jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz'] due to not_if
2015-04-16 16:43:11,324 - Execute['mkdir -p /usr/jdk64 ; cd /usr/jdk64 ; tar -xf /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/AMBARI-artifacts//jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz > /dev/null 2>&1'] {'not_if': 'test -e /usr/jdk64/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java', 'path': ['/bin', '/usr/bin/']}
2015-04-16 16:43:11,333 - Skipping Execute['mkdir -p /usr/jdk64 ; cd /usr/jdk64 ; tar -xf /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/AMBARI-artifacts//jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz > /dev/null 2>&1'] due to not_if
2015-04-16 16:43:11,564 - Package['hadoop_2_2_*-yarn'] {}
2015-04-16 16:43:11,825 - Installing package hadoop_2_2_*-yarn ('/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install hadoop_2_2_*-yarn')
```

Im' using ambari 1.7 and have been following [this](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/introducing-apache-ambari-deploying-managing-apache-hadoop/) installation guide.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

With Ambari 2.2 (HDP2.3.4.0) i'm seing the same issue:

Python script has been killed due to timeout after waiting 1800 secs

Can be solved by setting the timeout (agent.package.install.task.timeout=1800) in /etc/ambari-server/conf/ambari.properties

Paul

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue,

Its the problem with the servers where all these packages are downloading. 
When the response from these servers are taking too much time causes this error. Even though this error is not a problem maker. You can try some other mirrors to install the package or manually you can install in your host. After that `ambari` will check whether its properly installed or not. If it found to be installed properly it will automatically try to install the next package which is in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by adding

[security] force_https_protocol=PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2

to /etc/ambari-agent/conf/ambari-agent.ini file and it worked fine.